# Remove new line character after a specific word ignore space and tab

Tags: unix

I am parsing a sql script using unix. If `FROM` is a first word then merge it with previous line. If `FROM` is last word in line then we need to merge it with next line. E.g.:

```
A
FROM 
B
```

I want the result as

```
A FROM B
```

avoid any space and tabs.

Code:

```
cat A.txt | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s|[Ff][Rr][Oo][Mm][\s\t]*\n|FROM |g;s/\n\s*\t*[Ff][Rr][Oo][Mm]/ FROM/g' >B.txt
```

Comment: Please show the code you got by now

Comment: Do they end properly in `;`?

Comment: I basically want to get source table name from sql query. For that I am taking next word after 'from'. Which is working fine. But, in some cases, 'From' is the last word in the line and tablename is next line. So, I want to remove new line after 'from'. code i am using : cat A.txt | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s|[Ff][Rr][Oo][Mm][\s\t]*\n|FROM |g;s/\n\s*\t*[Ff][Rr][Oo][Mm]/ FROM/g' >B.txt

Comment: Regardless of the precise solution, you want to avoid the [useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one using GNU awk and `gensub`. It replaces combination of spaces, newlines and tabs (carriage return omitted due to unix tag) before and after the word `FROM`. It uses empty `RS` as record separator, meaning that a record ends in an empty line or the end of file.

```sh
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=""}{$0=gensub(/[ \t\n]+(FROM)[ \t\n]+/," \\1 ","g")}1' file
A FROM B
```

If you just want the word that comes after `FROM`:

```sh
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=""}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i=="FROM")print $(i+1)}' file
B
```

Both will fail if your query has `FROM` in the `WHERE` part values, like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE variable='DEATH COMES FROM ABOVE';
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am separating where clause in another file and then concatenating it after my task to avoid this problem.